# Is there a way to reliably go back and forth in file history

Tags: buffers, multiple-files

I would like to go to the file I just edited last and next kind of like MRU plugins do.

`:bnext` and `:bprev` works sometimes, but more often than not I just end up in some obscure file I don't remember editing and forced to fall back to MRU plugin.

Is there a way to fix it?

`Ctrl-^` swaps between two last files. What is the best way to navigate between more?

I understand it might be tricky but I would agree to anything that can improve current `:bn` `:bp` behavior. The buffers I often see are totally out of place. Maybe there is a plugin that can keep track of the recent files and provide hooks so I can create mappings?

Replying to comments cleared up my thoughts a bit. I believe what I want is to be able to move through files in order of latest saves. That way if I go back in history the order won't change until I save the file which then becomes last and make one step "back" to the file saved right before that, i.e. the one I've started from.

Something like `Ctrl-O` `Ctrl-I` pair that switches files immediately without jumping around the current buffer. Sort of like `u` and `U` in `netrw`:

```
u   Change to recently-visited directory                 |netrw-u|
U   Change to subsequently-visited directory             |netrw-U|
```

Comment: By "the file I just edited last" do you literally mean "the file I most recently made edits to"? Or do you just mean the last one that you had visible in Vim?

Comment: If the latter, I personally just mash `Ctrl-O` (or sometimes `Ctrl-T`) till I get there.

Comment: Yes that's what I do too `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I`. But it jumps between edit points and that breaks the flow. All I want to go back and forth between buffers in order of access. How plugins display a list of most recent files? Do they keep track of them internally?

Comment: `Ctrl-^` swaps between two last files. But what is the best way to navigate between more?

Comment: By access, it's still not clear if you mean the order they were opened, written to, in a focused window, or changed.

`Ctrl-O/I` are window-specific fwiw, while MRU is usually global.

If you do want order by most recently accessed, as soon as you jump back once, the order of the list changes, further complicating things.

Comment: Yes I understand but I agree to anything that can improve current `:bn` `:bp` behavior. The buffers I often see are totally out of place. Maybe there is a plugin that can keep track of the recent files and provide hooks so I can create mappings? Something like `Ctrl-O` that goes to prev file immediately without jumping around the current buffer.

Comment: Using marks may be another option. If you know you're going to come back to a file. Just mark it! Use the capital letter marks to make them persist even after restarting vim! For example `mA` will mark the current file to A, and then you can simply go back by using ``A`

Comment: The problem is I don't know it upfront. I usually edit controller, view, model, styles and scripts together. And I normally jump back and forth between files as I need to apply changes in few places.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a little function to repeatedly hit CTRL-O for me, until the buffer changes.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/back_to_recent_buffer.vim).  I mapped it to CTRL-U but you could override CTRL-O if you wanted to.

```
function! GoBackToRecentBuffer()
  let startName = bufname('%')
  while 1
    exe "normal! \<c-o>"
    let nowName = bufname('%')
    if nowName != startName
      break
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-U> :call GoBackToRecentBuffer()<Enter>
```

You could probably write something similar for `<C-I>`.

Issues:

- If there is no previous buffer, it will continue silently looping until you hit CTRL-C!

Related:

- `:jumps` lists the historical locations that CTRL-O will step back through.
- Vim's default CTRL-T is a good alternative to mashing CTRL-O, because it is coarser grained: it moves back through tag jumps only.

Comment: Vim seems to only offer one level of MRU file history, exposed on CTRL-^.  However I have noticed when using `:kwbd` to close a few buffers, that Vim does step back to the previous buffers in the expected reverse-historical order.  Perhaps Vim has a MRU list which it isn't sharing with us, or perhaps it chooses which buffer to fall back to based on the CTRL-O location history (`:jumps`).

Comment: Alternatively, `autocmd InsertLeave * normal mZ` will remember the last edited file in the global mark *Z*. You can get back to it with `g'Z`.
//
I have `nmap <C-y> g'Z` but I still tend to use Ctrl-U more often.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`:ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als) to show all buffers. For example:

```
:ls
  1      "vim.markdown"                 line 160
  2      "ext.markdown"                 line 0
  3 #    "~/to"                         line 1
  4 %a   "~/TODO"                       line 68
```

To go back to buffer `ext.markdown`, use `:e +Nbuf`, where `N` is the buffer number from the first column. For example: `:e +2buf`.

You can create a simple function for a more interactive experience:

```
fun! ChooseBuf()
    redir => buffers
        silent ls
    redir end

    echo l:buffers
    let l:choice = input('Which one: ')
    execute ':edit +' . l:choice . 'buf'
endfun
command! ChooseBuf call ChooseBuf()
nnoremap <Leader>b :call ChooseBuf()<CR>
```

After using `:ChooseBuf` or `<Leader>b` you can just type the number of the buffer you want to edit.

This is not *quite* "most recently used", since the order is "most recently opened" (this is probably also why `:bnext`/`:bprev` don't work as you expect).

Answer (score 5):

`<C-6>` is what you need, that takes you back to the previous buffer you had open before the current one. There are also `:bprev`& `:bnext` which you could use for the same.

Comment: `<C-6>` isn't bad but I can't use that to jump back two buffers. `bprev` and `bnext` are not in order of jumps.

Comment: Yea I don't think there's any good native way to go deeper into the history. You'd have to use some MRU plugin, even CtrlP has one, there must be others

Comment: Note: it's not `<C-6>`, it's `<C-^>`. While on many terminal emulators there is no distinction, on some (including the one that ships with OS X), there is. For the latter case, the use of the `Shift` key is required (assuming Qwerty layout).

Comment: @tommcdo interesting, I am on osx, but use iterm instead of the terminal.app, it works the same for me. Requiring Shift key on it would be a bummer.

Comment: Come to think of it, it might just be that my OS is grabbing that key binding and not propagating it to Vim. My OS must be stopped!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `:oldfiles` to get a list of files you edited.

The list will have numbers associated with filenames. Pick a file, note the number (say 14) and open it with `:edit #<14`

You can also run other commands on that file or pass multiple files to a command at once. More about this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29692602/1953718)

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29688194/5358968) in the link taught me `:bro[wse] ol[dfiles][!]`