# How to come out to the previous file in vi after entering a file with 'gf'?

Tags: multiple-files, navigation

When using vi for a file A, if I want to go to a file B when the cursor is on file B's filename, I press `gf` and vi opens file B. After navigating inside file B, if I want to come out to file A, what is the correct key? I know that if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> several times, I can come back to file A, and if I do `:rewind`, I can come back out to the first file that I opened with vi. But I want to know the key to come back out just one file when I went into a file using many `gf` commands.

I found from the [official vi manual](https://www.vi-improved.org/vimusermanual.pdf), that I can mark a global position (not local to a file) using capital letter, and can come to that position while editing another file by coming to that tag. Like `mF` in file A and the in file B `'F` to come to the mark 'F' in file A. This is usually what I want but I'm curious if I can come out just one file as in my question.

**ADD**
I know there is ctrl+^ which comes to the previous file but it's always 'previous' file so we cannot come back out to the previous-previous file when we used multiple 'gf' commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to reliably go back and forth in file history](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/is-there-a-way-to-reliably-go-back-and-forth-in-file-history)

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<C-o>` takes you to the last position in the jumplist, which may be in the previous buffer or in the current one, depending on how you are used to move around. FWIW, since I mostly use jump motions for moving around, `<C-o>` rarely puts me back in the last buffer I edited so I wouldn't consider it as a proper "previous buffer".

Actually, there is no proper universal "previous buffer" command and I think there is amissed opportunity, here.

After `gf`, you can do `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` on some keyboards) to come back to what Vim calls "alternate file". Note that the "alternate file" is not exactly the same as "previous buffer" in all situations but it is a good enough replacement in this case.

`:b#` is a command-line mode alternative.

See `:help ctrl-^`, `:help :buffer`, and `:help cmdline-special`.

Comment: Yes, I myself had found ctrl-^ later but it's always previous file. So if I go into files A B C using gf, then if I press ctrl^ twice in file C, it becmes B C not B A. It repeats B C B C.. never going back to file A.

Comment: A I said, there is no "previous buffer" in Vim. `<C-^>` kind of fits the bill only in the exact scenario you described in your question.